# Laravel Voyager Belongs To relationship in form displays “Searching”

Tags: laravel, voyager

**Version information**

Laravel: v7.26.1

Voyager: v1.4.2

PHP: 7.4.5

Database: MySQL 7.4.8

**Description**

I'm trying to solve one problem but I'm not doing well.
There are 2 tables:

*table1 (id, nameInTable1, active, create_at, update_at)*

*table2 (id, nameInTable1, nameInTable2, active, create_at, update_at)*

I made a BREAD for both tables. I can now enter data via the form (and it works) in both tables.
However, I wanted to add that in the second table I put "select" over the form so that I could select the names from the first table via the drop-down list.

When I followed the documentation and the video, and when I followed the steps, the data from the first table does not appear in the drop-down list when I fill in the second.

**Steps To Reproduce**

Here is a concrete example:

This is what Table 1 looks like

*reklamekonvencija (id, konvencijanaziv, aktivan, created_at, updated_at)*

The model for this table looks like the image below

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class Reklamekonvencija extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'reklamekonvencija';
    protected $fillable = ['id','konvencijanaziv','aktivan','created_at','updated_at']; 
    
    public function scopeActive($query)
    {
        return $query->where('aktivan', 1);
    }
    public function scopeInactive($query)
    {
        return $query->where('aktivan', 0);
    }
    
}
```

And BREAD looks like this:

[BREAD of table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjRJD.png)

And this is what Table 2 looks like

*reklame (id konvencijanaziv oglasivac nazivReklame nazivDelaMuzike autor trajanje created_at updated_at)*

This is what the model looks like:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class Reklame extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'reklame';
    protected $fillable = ['id','konvencijanaziv', 'oglasivac', 'nazivReklame', 'nazivDelaMuzike', 'autor', 'trajanje', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];

    public function scopeActive($query)
    {
        return $query->where('aktivan', 1);
    }
    public function scopeInactive($query)
    {
        return $query->where('aktivan', 0);
    }
    
}
```

This is what BREAD for Table 2 looks like:

[BREAD of table 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yS74z.png)

When I want to insert the data in Table 2 now, it looks like this:

[Add from drop down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNxl7.png)

The data in Table 1 do not appear in the drop-down list, although they do exist.

I folow the instruction from the site, and i followed the instructions of other people, mostly the steps are similar, but to do it still doesn't work..

Do you have any advice in which direction to look where I might be wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi Nikola, welcome to SO. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/)  and avoid posting [code images](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) into your question. By doing small improvements you can increase the likelihood to have your question answered.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will try to better describe the problem with as few pictures as possible.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a problem. I didn't pay attention to the fact that my ad block was turned on, it was causing a problem with the search, so it just pointed to "search" in the field where it was supposed to show the list of names from the other table.